# MWAA without workers

Tags: airflow, mwaa

### My current undestanding of MWAA

MWAA uses Fargate for Scheduler(s) and Worker(s). MWAA must have at least 1 Scheduler, it must be Fargate, I assume 24/7 endless process (to avoid decomissioning). Scheduler Fargate machine is also running Celery executor.

When triggered, DAG get splitted into tasks by Executor, each task is added to queue, from which it's pulled by Workers. In case of bash operator, the task is submitted to Fargate Worker and executed there.

Workers scaling is managed by Fargate, you only specify min/max count. In case of task submitted in the same time the worker decomissioning is triggered - it may fail (know issue).

### Questions

Suppose execution of single-task DAG. Task is executed on another AWS service, i.e. EMR (`EmrAddStepsOperator`).

1. Is `EmrAddStepsOperator` submitted to MWAA Fargate Worker first and only then to EMR? Or it's submitted directly to EMR from MWAA Scheduler?
2. In case all my tasks are executed at EMR, do I need MWAA workers at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the same regardless of MWAA / Google Cloud Composer / something else.

Airflow is orchestrator tool. Tasks are running on Airflow workers but the "core" of the tasks can be executed on another service. Think about use case of task that executing some SQL. the actual computing of the SQL is done on the database not on the machine that submitted the SQL job. Airflow must create a task for each operator this task must run on Airflow worker. If the tasks perform computing/processing on the worker itself or submit a job to another service and just wait for response that is depended on the task itself.

To explain better:
The `execute()` function that any operator must implement is running on your Celery worker. In this function there can be parts of code where you are submitting a job to another service like EMR. In these cases you also have the choice if you want to hold on the Celery worker until the external service (EMR) returns an answer (Synchronous manner) or release the Celery worker to do something else in the mean time (run another task). That is decided by how the operator was implemented.

So to answer your questions:

1. When Airflow scheduler execute `EmrAddStepsOperator` a task will be created for it. The task will be processed by the `CeleryExecutor` and will be sent to Celery worker. When the tasks will start running it will execute [add_job_flow_steps](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bb1d79cb81c5a5a80f97ab4fecfa7db7a52c7b4b/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr_add_steps.py#L99) which only then a step will be submitted to EMR.
2. Yes because `CeleryExecutor` submit tasks to Celery workers. It doesn't know/care about what services your tasks is interacting with. That said - if your tasks are only submitting jobs to other services you probably don't need workers with high memory/cpu as the workers don't do significant processing.

Comment: great answer, thanks you!